# Как загрузить и запустить скрипт python на виртуальной машине яндекс

Tags: python, ubuntu, виртуальная-машина

Подскажите как загрузить и запустить скрипт python на виртуальной машине яндекс. Создал виртуальную машину, установил там python и все необходимые библиотеки. Мой скрипт находится у меня на локальной машине. На виртуалке ОС Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: ```$ man scp```?

Comment: `filezilla`, `winscp`?